# at least once with many group probability

Tags: probability

There are 30 colored chips with 10 different colors. We make a selection of 10 chips are random. We sample without replacement. Each color is assigned to 3 chips. What is the probability that all 3 chips will be present of at least one color?

Could someone clarify me on this? I performed a simulation and I got approximately 0.28, but I cannot find the theoretical result. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I understood from the given description.

Short answer:
$$\frac{{10\choose 1}{27\choose 7}}{{30\choose 10}}\approx 0.3$$
Comment: The $10$ chips selected can have $1,2,3$ colored triplets of chips. For example, ${10\choose 1}$ ways to choose a color (so $3$ chips will have this color) and ${27\choose 7}$ ways to choose other colored chips (including the triplets of same color.

Long answer:
$$\frac{\left[{10\choose 1}{27\choose 7}-{10\choose 2}{24\choose 4}\right]+\left[{10\choose 2}{27\choose 4}-{10\choose 3}{21\choose 1}\right]+\left[{10\choose 3}{21\choose 1}\right]}{{30\choose 10}}=\frac{{10\choose 1}{27\choose 7}}{{30\choose 10}}\approx 0.3.$$
Comment: The first brackets count the number of events with exactly one triplet of same color, second count exactly two triplets and third count exactly three triplets of same color each.

Comment: what i did was: say, a1,a2,a3 events is one, two, and three triplets of the same color. so P(a1∪ a2 ∪ a3) = p(a1) + p(a2) +p(a3) - p(a1*a2) -  p(a1*a3) -  p(a3*a2) + p(a1*a2*a3) =  p(a1) + p(a2) +p(a3) , instead of p(a1) - p(a2) +p(a3) like you did.  why p(a2) is substracted instead of being added?

Comment: Let me clarify: there are $30$ chips of $10$ different colors, that is, $3$ black, $3$ red, $3$ green, $3$ blue, ... , $3$ white. You select $10$ chips at random and want to know the probability that at least one triplet of same color (e.g. $3$ black and other $7$ different colors, $3$ black, $3$ white and other $6$ different colors, etc). Then, it should be simply $\frac{{10\choose 1}{27\choose 7}}{{30\choose 10}}\approx 0.3$, because it includes all three cases already.